# Reading seekarc position value in Android

Tags: java, android

I am beginner in Android. I created a circular `seekarc` with temperature showing text and I added in middle of `seekarc`. The text value is starting with 10 and ending with value is 20.

I want to read each text value position for `seekarc`. If the text value position is `false`, then `seekarc` value position is also `false`.

How can I achieve this? Can any one help me?

Below is my code:

```
    seekarc = (SeekArc) v.findViewById(R.id.seekAr);
    seekArcprogres = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.seekArcProgres);
    seekarc.setOnSeekArcChangeListener(new SeekArc.OnSeekArcChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(
                SeekArc seekArc, final int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            seekArcprogres.setText(String.valueOf(progress + 10));


            switch (progress) {
                case 0:
                    Op.processInputCmd(getArguments().getString(""), Manager.Command.EMP_16, false);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    Op.processACButtonInputCmd(getArguments().getString(""), Manager.Command.EMP_10, false);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    ;
                    Op.processInputCmd(getArguments().getString(""), Manager.Command.EMP_11, false);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Op.processInputCmd(getArguments().getString(""), Manager.Command.EMP_12, false);
                    break;
            }

           seekArcprogres.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Op.processInputCmd(getArguments().getString(""), Manager.Command.EMP_10_LR, false);
                }

            });
            seekArcprogres.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                    Op.processInputCmd(getArguments().getString(""), Manager.Command.EMP_10_LR, true);
                    return true;
                }

            });

            seekArcprogres.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Op.processInputCmd(getArguments().getString(""), Manager.Command.EMP_11_LR, false);
                }

            });
            seekArcprogres.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                    Op.processInputCmd(getArguments().getString(""), Manager.Command.EMP_17_LR, true);
                    return true;
                }
         @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(
                SeekArc seekArc) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(
                SeekArc seekArc) {


        }
    });
```